# How to reset selection after selecting item in PieChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

does anyone know, how to reset selected item in MPAndroid Charts - PieChart? 
I need to be able to click on one item for example "ten tousand" times, but every second time it gives me **onNothingSelected()** event not **onValueSelected()**

I need call only onValueSelected() event.

Can someone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 12):

Wow, I really wanted the answer and.. finally, I solved this problem.

The answer is very simple.

```
chart.getOnTouchListener().setLastHighlighted(null);    
chart.highlightValues(null);
```

Before set highlightValues as null, You need to also initialize the last touched highlighted value too!

Comment: I see just adding chart.highlightValues(null); works. Why do we need the first line and in what case it would be needed?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you solved your problem. But, in case someone have the same problem, here is one solution using Bar Charts:

```
// global variables
protected static Entry entry;
protected static int index;
protected static Highlight highlight;

// function where the listener is defined
protected void manipulateChart(){

    final BarChart mChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.your_chart);

    // listener
    mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
                // set global variables
                entry = e;
                index = dataSetIndex;
                highlight = h;

                mChart.highlightValues(null);
                // ... your code ...
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {
            onValueSelected(entry, index, highlight);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's in the documentation: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart

Inside your `onValueSelected()` method, call

```
chart.highlightValues(null);
```

to undo all highlighting.

Comment: It only clear highlight, but I need unselect it.. If i click on it, onValueSelected() is called, but if i click on it second time, onNothingSelected() is called, but i need again onValueSelected()

Comment: Then call onValueSelected() from onNothingSelected()

Comment: onNothingSelected has no input parameters, I need them in onValueSelected

Answer (score 0):

Using Kotlin, and v3.1.0 of MP Android Chart:

At the end of `onValueSelected()` call

```
chart.isSelected = false
chart.highlightValues(null)
```

The `chart.isSelected` is a property coming from the `View` class, and deselecting the entire chart also deselects the selected/highlighted entry.

Answer (score 0):

As @Phillip says you can call onValueSelected() from onNothingSelected(),
For Entry Create a globar variable and initialize it in onValueSelected(),as we know the selected entry is same

```
override fun onValueSelected(e: Entry?, h: Highlight?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onValueSelected: e ${e.toString()}")
        Log.d(TAG, "onValueSelected: h ${h.toString()}")

        e!!.y += 10.0f
        lastEntry = e
        binding.barChart.invalidate()

    }

    override fun onNothingSelected() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onNothingSelected: called")

        onValueSelected(lastEntry,null)
    }
```